# Where exactly does the qt example network-chat send message?

Tags: c++, qt

From the qt offical example [network-chat](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/network/network-chat/connection.cpp?h=6.4).

I want to find by which code sends the network message. From the UI code we can find this returnPressed calling `client.sendMessage`:

```
void ChatDialog::returnPressed()
{...
        client.sendMessage(text);
...
}
```

It finally calls `Connection::sendMessage`:

```
bool Connection::sendMessage(const QString &message)
{
    if (message.isEmpty())
        return false;

    writer.startMap(1);
    writer.append(PlainText);
    writer.append(message);
    writer.endMap();
    return true;
}
```

However, writer is just a message-data-block-generator:

```
QCborStreamWriter writer;
```

It doesn't really send the message.

BTW, I consulted another example [fortuneserver](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/network/fortuneserver/server.cpp) from which I can exactly find the sending message code

```
void Server::sendFortune(){
...
QTcpSocket *clientConnection = tcpServer->nextPendingConnection();
...
clientConnection->write(block);
}
```

Comment: The connection between the QCBorStreamWriter and the QTcpSocket is done within [QCBorStreamWriter's ctor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcborstreamwriter.html#QCborStreamWriter)

Comment: @chehrlic, yes, you're exactly right. Thanks!